# Cannot find module 'date Format'

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I have a project using nodejs.
I want to format the date using dateformat.
when I try on local it works, but when I upload it to the server, dateformat is unreadable (cannot find module 'date format')

[image]

this is my code

```
var date = new Date();
    var dateFormat = require('dateFormat');
    var periode = dateFormat(date, "yyyy-mm");
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you installed the module `dateformat` ? (https://www.npmjs.com/package/dateformat) Also, change the uppercase `F` to a lowercase.

Comment: did you install all the dependencies on the server? make sure you have installed dateFormat module

Comment: try installing this **npm install dateformat**

Comment: thank you all, F must to a lowercase and dateformat must be global variable in app.js

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you haven't added the module to the project, you can go to the project directory and run the below command or add this module globally

```
> npm install dateFormat
```

Comment: thank you, 
this is great
F must to a lowercase and dateformat must be global variable in app.js

Comment: Welcome to the community glad my answer helped you !

Answer (score 0):

npm install dateFormat getting error
npm install dateFormat
npm ERR! code ENOVERSIONS
npm ERR! No valid versions available for dateFormat

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/yourprojectname/.npm/_logs/2022-06-08T12_02_03_215Z-debug.log

```
var date = new Date();
    var dateFormat = require('dateformat');
    var periode = dateformat(date, "yyyy-mm");
install 
npm install dateformat
```

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
npm i dateformat
```

Using the "F" will give an error: "no such versions available".